Could somebody check my understanding about the notion of filtration is right or wrong?
everybody. I have some problem in understanding the notion of filtration about a stochastic process in stochastic calculus. Here, I'll write down my understanding about filtration through the random walk, which is a very simple discrete stochastic process. And I wonder if my understanding is right or wrong. If my understanding is not right somewhere, I hope someone can point it out and correct it. Thanks very much!
Assume $Z_{t}$ denotes the simple random walk.
$Z_{t}:=X_{1}+X_{2}+\cdots+X_{t},\space\space\space t\in\mathbb{N}$,
where $(X_{t})_{t\geq1}$ is a sequence of independent, identically distributed $\{−1, 1\}$ valued random variables.
Here, I first consider the natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_{t}$ of $Z_{t}$ (i.e., $\mathcal{F}_{t}=\sigma(Z_{s},s\leq t)$) and write down the expression of $\mathcal{F}_{0}$, $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{2}$ based on my understanding.
$\mathcal{F}_{0}=\{\emptyset,\Omega_{0}\}$.
I think the form of $\mathcal{F}_{0}$ is to make sure $Z_{0}$ takes a contant value, which is usually set to be 0, because any random variable, which is $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$-measurable, takes contant value with probability one. So, $\Omega_{0}$ may have no analytic expression.
$\mathcal{F}_{1}=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{-1\},\Omega_{1}\}$.
The singletons, such as $\{1\}$ and $\{-1\}$, contained in $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ denote all the possible paths $Z_{t}$ can take up to $t=1$. Here, I omit the value of $Z_{0}$, which is commonly set to be $0$. Thus, the expression of $\Omega_{1}$ is $\Omega_{1}=\{1,-1\}$.
$\mathcal{F}_{2}=\{\emptyset,\{(1,0)\},\{(1,2)\},\{(-1,0)\},\{(-1,-2)\},\{(1,0),(1,2)\},\{(1,0),(-1,0)\},\{(1,0),(-1,-2)\},\{(1,2),(-1,0)\},\{(1,2),(-1,-2)\},\{(-1,0),(-1,-2)\},\{(1,2),(-1,0),(-1,-2)\},\{(1,0),(-1,0),(-1,-2)\},\{(1,0),(1,2),(-1,-2)\},\{(1,0),(1,2),(-1,0)\},\Omega_{2}\}.$
For $(i,j)$ in $\mathcal{F}_{2}$, $i$ denotes the value of $Z_{1}$ and $j$ denotes the value of $Z_{2}$. The singletons, such as $\{(1,0)\},\{(1,2)\},\{(-1,0)\}$ and $\{(-1,-2)\}$, contained in $\mathcal{F}_{2}$ are all the possible paths $Z_{t}$ can take up to $t=2$. The other elements contained in $Z_{t}$ are the sets based on the four singletons, which is a requirement of $\sigma$-algebra. Thus, the expression of $\Omega_{2}$ is $\Omega_{2}=\{(1,0),(1,2),(-1,0),(-1,-2)\}$.
Towards the relationship $\mathcal{F}_{1}\subset \mathcal{F}_{2}$, the element $\{1\}$ in $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ corresponds to the element $\{(1,0),(1,2)\}$ in $\mathcal{F}_{2}$, the element $\{-1\}$ in $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ corresponds to the element $\{(-1,0),(-1,-2)\}$ in $\mathcal{F}_{2}$, and $\Omega_{1}$ corresponds to $\Omega_{2}$.
However, there may be more than one filtration associated with a stochastic process. Here, I'll give another filtration $\mathcal{G}_{t}$ of $Z_{t}$ based on my understandiong.
For $\mathcal{G}_{t}$, only the case of $Z_{t}$, where $X_{\tau}$ ($\tau \leq t$) takes $1$ when $\tau$ is even, is considered.
$\mathcal{G}_{0}=\{\emptyset,\Omega_{0}\}$.
$\mathcal{G}_{1}=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{-1\},\Omega_{1}\}$.
$\Omega_{1}=\{1,-1\}$.
$\mathcal{G}_{2}=\{\emptyset,\{(1,2)\},\{(-1,0)\},\{(1,2),(-1,0)\},\{(1,0),(-1,-2)\},\{(1,2),(1,0),(-1,-2)\},\{(-1,0),(1,0),(-1,-2)\},\Omega_{2}\}.$
$\Omega_{2}=\{(1,0),(1,2),(-1,0),(-1,-2)\}$.
Thus, $\mathcal{F}_{t}$ is larger than $\mathcal{G}_{t}$, i.e., $\mathcal{G}_{t}\subset \mathcal{F}_{t}$.
At this point, I have demonstrated my understanding about the notion of filtration through the simple discrete stochastic process, random walk. I hope somebody can check if my understanding is right or wrong. Thanks very much!

looks like a solution verification question, ask this type of question needs to tell us where is you doubt, and why so. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context.
